# Entity reference field to show translation of nodes

Tags: 7, entities, i18n-l10n

I have a content type "Genetic Test" which has an entity reference field (select list) where I can select nodes of the content type "Material".
The Material nodes all have English set as their source language, but they are also translated in Dutch and French (entity translation).

The problem I'm having is, when I edit a node of the type "Genetic Test" with the interface language set to English, the select list shows the Material nodes, but when I change the interface language to Dutch or French the list is empty.

So my question is, how do I get the select list to show the Dutch or French node titles of the content type Material when I'm editing the Genetic Test node in said languages?

I hope I made myself clear a bit, English isn't my first language.

Thank you in advance for any help.

BTW: I'm working in Drupal 7.

Comment: I stumbled upon this, although it's old it may still help. I have a similar configuration with ER field and multilingual Drupal 7, and I can see nodes from all languages listed as choices for the field, in any interface langugae. Are you using a Views ER display for the field widget? Maybe you have it filtered to show only English nodes? Are you using `Synchronize translations`?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you have already taken care of this but I think you would need to add [title](http://drupal.org/project/title) module as well since the title is not an entity by default and wont work with the entity translation module.

Another thing would to keep the language as neutral rather than keeping it English. Internally drupal would fetch the nodes with the lan

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am already using the title module. And I tried setting the source language to neutral but that way I can't translate the node in different languages.